# How to run Angular 4 project without npm server and using tomcat in local machine

Tags: angular, tomcat7

I want to run my Angular 4 project using tomcat. So please any one can help me in this.

Comment: Angular is a client side library, Tomcat is mostly used for deploying server application.  A simple web server should suffice (like Apache2).

Comment: I agree with @Cuball - unless you have a specific reason for *needing* a Tomcat server, you should use Apache or Nginx or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular CLI, run the build command as follows (note the period at the end):

ng build -prod --base-href .

This will build the bundles into the dist directory of your project. Copy the dist directory to the webapps/ROOT dir of your Tomcat installation dir.

Start Tomcat and open the following URL in your browser:
http://localhost:8080/dist

This is pretty much it.

Comment: It's worth noting that `ng build` by default generates an unoptimized development build - if you're actually deploying your app for public use, `ng build -prod` should be used.